# cross compilation of a c program from x86 to arm with cython library

Tags: c, python-3.x, linux, gcc, makefile

I would like to compile a C program that I made for my raspberry pi from my PC.

My program uses the rt, pthread and cython libraries.

I use the arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc compiler for this and I made a makefile:

```
CC = gcc

CC_ARM = arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

CFLAGS = -I -g -Wall

INCLUDES = -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I/

LIBS = -lrt -lpthread -lpython3.8

SRCS = main.c Config_radio.c

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

MAIN = radio

ARM = radio_arm

.PHONY: depend clean

all:    $(MAIN)
        @echo  radio has been compiled

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(ARM): $(OBJS)
        $(CC_ARM) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(ARM) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@

clean:
        $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)

depend: $(SRCS)
        makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^
```

When I compile with gcc, the compilation succeed but when I try to compile with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc I get the following error:

```
make radio_arm
gcc -I -g -Wall -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I/ -c main.c  -o main.o
gcc -I -g -Wall -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I/ -c Config_radio.c  -o Config_radio.o
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I -g -Wall -I/usr/include/python3.8 -I/ -o radio_arm main.o Config_radio.o  -lrt -lpthread -lpython3.8
main.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:28 : radio_arm] Erreur 1
```

I think my libraries don't work with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.

Can you explain to me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `gcc` to compile `main.o`.  That GCC is presumably the native compiler of your x86 system.  Therefore, `main.o` will have x86 code in it and it cannot be linked into an ARM program.

Make sure **all** your objects and **all** the libraries you are linking were compiled with the ARM toolchain and then things should be fine.

Also, the `-I/usr/include/python3.8` looks like a problem to me because those will be the headers for the native Python on your system, not a Python that has been cross-compiled for ARM.  It might work, but it seems pretty risky.  Also `-I` by itself and `-I/` don't really make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I fixed my Makefile and like you said I get the following error: 
`fatal error: arm-linux-gnueabihf/python3.8/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
   13 | #  include <arm-linux-gnueabihf/python3.8/pyconfig.h> `

Anyone know what packages to install to fix this ?

Comment: I imagine pyconfig.h would get generated as part of the Python compilation/build process if it's not being found now.  It's unlikely that your particular Linux distribution has a cross-compiled Python 3.8 package, so you'll just have to compile it yourself using your cross compiler and then install it to a directory somewhere.

Comment: compiling on my raspberry pi with this makefile worked. I will try to find the dependencies to install on my Ubuntu PC. Thanks again for your help